# Return object with highest number from array containing multiple objects

Tags: javascript

I was able to figure out how to return the highest number from a associative array with multiple objects. But I need the whole object.

I prepared this example:

```js
var data = [
     { nr: 235, text: "foo" }
    ,{ nr: 351, text: "bar" }
];

var highestNr = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data).map(function(e) {
             return data[e]['nr'];
         }));
                
var index = "???";

console.log("Highest 'nr': " + highestNr);
console.log("Index at nr "+ highestNr + ": " + index);

//console.log(data[index]);
```

I need the index or the whole object. I need to show the text from the object with the highest number.

Comment: technical point, you haven't got an associative array here. You've got an array containing two objects. JS doesn't have associative arrays, it has objects - although it is possible to use them in a similar way to you might use an associative array in, say, PHP, e.g. by looping through the properties of the object.

Comment: Once you have the highest number can't you just filter the array on that value?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: you could, but see the answer from NinaScholz for a better technique.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the hint. I changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could reduce the array by selecting the one with a greater value.

```js
var data = [{ nr: 235, text: "foo" }, { nr: 351, text: "bar" }], 
    topNr = data.reduce((a, b) => a.nr > b.nr ? a : b);

console.log(topNr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "sort" the array by "nr" property in descending order and get first element "[0]"

```js
var data = [
     { nr: 235, text: "foo" }
    ,{ nr: 351, text: "bar" }
];

// slice added so that original data is not mutated
var result = data.slice(0).sort((a,b) => b.nr - a.nr)[0]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Using sort is a good idea, especially if you also wanted the `nth` highest etc.  But it might be worth pointing out this will mutate the array, so you might want to do `[].concat(data).sort(` if this is not desired.

Comment: Sorting is fine for small lists.  But it's going to be `O(n log n)`, whereas this can be done in `O(n)` as the `reduce` answers show.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for pointing complexity. Correct, it depends upon the size of array.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method:

```js
var data = [
     { nr: 235, text: "foo" }
    ,{ nr: 351, text: "bar" }
];

var highestNr = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(data).map(function(e) {
    return data[e]['nr'];
}));
                
var index = data.findIndex(function(ln) {
    return ln.nr === highestNr;
});

console.log("Highest 'nr': " + highestNr);
console.log("Index at nr "+ highestNr + ": " + index);

//console.log(data[index]);
```